# Performance of Java code from Groovy script

Tags: java, groovy, scripting

I have a method in java and invoke it from java, then I invoke the same method from groovy. Is there any impact in terms of performance? When I run the java code from groovy, that code is interpreted?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run java from groovy, that part becomes normal java execution. In fact, running 'java' code from groovy is actually a solution to any performance problem you may come up with groovy scripts. See some [comment](http://blog.evan-wong.com/2012/04/java-vs-groovy-vs-scala-simple.html) or this question [Just how scalable is Grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359534/just-how-scalable-is-grails)  in that direction.